# receiving async POST response, need to update webpage

Tags: jquery, post, asynchronous, django-templates, django-views

So I am displaying a web page using the django framework. 
Now, I get asynchronous POST responses from the foursquare API when ever someone checks in to one of my locations.

This is kind of an odd problem.

My question: What would be the best way to update the webpage, without refreshing it, whenever my server receives a POST response from the foursquare API servers.
For now, in the view for handling the POST response, I just update some context variables and use those variables in another view to display stuff, but obviously the changes show only after refreshing the page.

I have looked into AJAX and understand that it is useful when client is aware of some event happening, which then makes a call to a function to receive some values and update part of a page like some div.

But in my case the client is not aware of any such event since the request is getting generate when someone checks in and the response is coming from the foursquare servers to my server.

I there some way to deal with this?
I have looked into dajax and dajaxice, but couldn't find how they could be useful.

I have seen some solutions in which I could add some JQuery to query the server at small regular intervals, but that does not seem optimal.

Any suggestions on what I should look into?

Turns out, web socket wont cut it, since I do not have any events occurring at the client side and I do not need full duplex communication; and Comet seems to be a heavy framework.I am looking into other stuff. Open to cool suggestion.

Comment: Please consider Server-sent Events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose:

1. [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)
2. Web socket for HTML5
3. [Server-sent Events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) for HTML5. For ie, you may need [polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource).

Comment: Cool I'll look into Comet. I did come across it but, I didn't read much about it thoroughly.

Comment: Turns out, web socket wont cut it, since I do not have any events occurring at the client side and I do not need full duplex communication; and Comet seems to be a heavy framework. Thanks!!

Comment: Full duplex communication means even something occurs at server side, you can also change the content of client side at that moment. If you don't care some old browsers like ie 6, you can choose it either.

Comment: Cool, thanks! SSE seems to be the way to go about it for what I need!